# Grep a resulting pipe multiple times

Tags: grep

I have a `grep` result and I want to filter some lines away by some given filter token. For example, given rows below, the desired output is `this is a desired line`.

```
This is a desired line
This is a desired line with filter token_1
This is a desired line with filter token_2
this is a undesired line
```

The command run `grep -rnw . -e "desired"`.

```
This is a desired line
This is a desired line with filter token_1
This is a desired line with filter token_2
```

How can I filter the lines with tokens `token_1` and `token_2`? I suspect to use the array feature `grep_ignores=( 'token_1' 'token_2' )` somehow, but my attempts sofar corrupt the escape `\n` character, which makes me think I should be using `awk` or `perl` smoehow.

Comment: Have you try a pipe `|`? `grep -rnw . -e "desired"|grep token`

Comment: If you want to skip lines with "token" use `grep -v token`

Comment: I do not have only one token, but a user-defined number of tokens

Comment: The challenge here is to "pipefy" some previous result.

Comment: How do you plan to get `this is a desired line`? That line doesn't appear in the output that you gave? Is the expected output supposed to be `This is a desired line`?

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto, how many tokens?

Comment: I wish to be flexible enough to not fix it beforehand. I mean, I could provided others as well in case the project grow bigger then before.

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto, again: how many, 2, 10, 100, 100000?

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto, check the answer of **dhm** :)

Comment: Dynamically assigned.

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto, you MUST have some estimation, by your words they may be 10T tokens. Do you have enough resources to handle so many of them. Every system have some limits.

Comment: Even our brain? Sad

Comment: @RomeoNinov I finished without the file itself: https://github.com/trouchet/sappio/blob/development/scripts/use-dependencies.sh

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto, good :) I am not fan of arrays, so if required will dig for another way

Comment: You should. Give arrays the element of trust. ;-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the list of patterns you want to exclude in a text file:

```
cat mypatterns.txt
token_1
token_2
```

Now pipe the result of your first grep to this expression:

```
grep -f mypatterns.txt  -v
```

Comment: Oh, I see. An elegant solution. Do you think it is possible to avoid this intermediary file somehow? I can remove it at the end of shell script, sure...

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto There are ways to do it solely in the command line (without the file), but since you have "a user-defined number of tokens" and they are "dynamically assigned", the right way is to "dynamically adjust" the file and let the code be static.

Comment: You know these are assigned "elegant" requirements, but could be very ugly defined, right!?

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto you could use *process substitution*, ex. in bash `... | grep -v -f <(printf '%s\n' "${grep_ignores[@]}")`

Comment: This is my solution sofar: https://github.com/trouchet/sappio/blob/development/scripts/use-dependencies.sh. It worked, but I will try yours. :-)

Comment: @steeldriver is this tag `<` correctly placed? It seems a bit odd to me. Maybe because I am not familiar to process substitution

Comment: It worked for me with this command `grep -rnw . -e "desired" | grep -v -f <(printf '%s\n' "${grepignore_tokens[@]}")` with `grepignore_tokens=('token_1' 'token_2')` :-)